# How to have class styles override composed style in CSS Modules without using important?

Tags: html, css, css-modules

I am using CSS Modules in my project and the composes command, like this:

```
// In one file

.btnSecondary {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

// In another file

.btnInteract {
  composes: btnSecondary from "../buttons.module.css";
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

And then to my surprise in the compiled webpage, the `align-self: flex-start;` is overruled by the `.btnSecondary` class, as can be seen here:

[image]

I can fix this problem by just using `!important` in the `btnInteract` class, but I would rather not do that everywhere. Another might ask why I even have `align-self: flex-end` in the `.btnSecondary` class. Well, it's because 99% of the time that's what I want in the other class. Just not in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS specificity hierarchy to the rescue!

You can override existing styles by using more specific element description.

```
.btnInteract {
  color: #deface;
}

// following selector is more important
.parent .btnInteract {
  color: #FB1;
}
```

Easier solution for your problem is using `id` attribute rather than `class`. In this case `id` attributes are more important than `class` attributes from the browser perspective.

Here is [the link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/css-specificity-hierarchy-what-you-need-to-know/) for the good article about this topic.